# Fetch RelatedItems in Amazon Product Api using Rails 4 Vacuum gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api, vacuum

I am integrating Amazon Product Api in my rails app. The only thing remaining now is fetching **related items** list when I am performing the `item_lookup` operation.

When I add `RelatedItems` in ResponseGroup like this:

```
    response = request.item_lookup(
    query: {
        'ItemId' => params[:id],
        'ResponseGroup' => "ItemAttributes,Images,Reviews,RelatedItems"
    }
    )
```

I get this error:

```
"Errors"=>{"Error"=>{"Code"=>"AWS.MissingParameterValueCombination", "Message"=>"Your request is missing a required parameter combination.  When ResponseGroup equals RelatedItems, RelationshipType must be present."}}}
```

It seems that I need to add `RelationshipType` in my query.

The issue is I have my categories being saved in the backend. The `search_index` and `keyword` is passed to the `item_search` operation where I fetch the  `ASIN` which I pass as param to `item_lookup` operation. The issue is how can I add **RelationshipType** over here and also that it has to dynamic as per the product being displayed.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

Could you simply add all existing RelationshipType values to your ItemLookup request. The RelationshiptType set is limited to 15 valid values, so you could include all of them into your request as follows:

```
response = request.item_lookup(
query: {
    'ItemId' => params[:id],
    'ResponseGroup' => "ItemAttributes,Images,Reviews,RelatedItems"
    ...
    'RelationshipType' => "Tracks,DigitalMusicArranger,DigitalMusicComposer,DigitalMusicConductor,DigitalMusicEnsemble,DigitalMusicLyricist,DigitalMusicPerformer,DigitalMusicPrimaryArtist,DigitalMusicProducer,DigitalMusicRemixer,DigitalMusicSongWriter,Episode,Season"
}
)
```